# how to use django-import-export in DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-import-export

The result of installing import-export and importing from the admin page
I get the following error

error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 639, in import_row
instance, new = self.get_or_init_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 334, in get_or_init_instance
instance = self.get_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 322, in get_instance
self.fields[f] for f in self.get_import_id_fields()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 322, in <listcomp>
self.fields[f] for f in self.get_import_id_fields()
KeyError: 'id'
```

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Country
from import_export.admin import ExportActionModelAdmin, ImportExportMixin, ImportMixin

@admin.register(Country)
class CountryAdmin(ImportExportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [  "country_ID", "iso_code", "cname_en"  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that the code is failing because it is trying to use a field to lookup existing objects which is not declared in your Resource `fields` list.

During import, `django-import-export` will try to match each csv row against existing entries in the DB table - if it finds them, then there will be an `update` operation, instead of a `create`.  This is to avoid the creation of duplicates.

By default, the import logic looks for a field called `id`.  However it looks like you have not declared this field in your `fields` list, or perhaps there is no 'id' field on your model.

You could perhaps fix this with:

```
fields - ('id',)
```

This is assuming that there is an `id` field on your model, and in your data source.

The [docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) cover this in more detail, and it is worth reading through the documented logic for imports in order to understand what is going on.  Additionally, setting a debugger and stepping through will save a lot of time in understanding any import issues.